# JMF Plugin for .mkv file type?

Tags: java, file, video, format, jmf

Is there one anywhere? I know that JMF is outdated, but I'm using it for a little application, and it can't read mkv files by default.

Alternatively, is there a method for converting the mkv format to a file type compatible with JMF, such as .mov or .avi?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no way to read an .mkv file with JMF

But, yes, you could convert it with a tool like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).  Frankly, JMF is more than just outdated...it's dead in the water and not going anywhere.  You might want to consider an alternative approach.